# Associações com Node.JS / Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express.js, sequelize-js

Boa noite caros amigos,

Estou desenvolvendo uma API com **Node.JS / Express / Sequelize** e preciso de uma ajuda. Como é a primeira vez que utilizo bancos relacionais com Node, não sei exatamente como fazer um relacionamento entre as tabelas ***Players*** e ***Teams***. A lógica é a seguinte:

- Um *player* pertence a somente um *team*;
- Um *team* pode ter um ou mais *players*;

Os models são os seguintes:

```js
class Player extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init({
            name: type: DataTypes.STRING,
            nickname: type: DataTypes.STRING,
            position_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            team_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        }, {
            sequelize
        });
    }

    static associate(models) {
        // ???????????????????????????????????????????
    }
}

class Team extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init({
            name: type: DataTypes.STRING,
        }, {
            sequelize
        });
    }

    static associate(models) {
        // ???????????????????????????????????????????
    }
}
```

**Qual a maneira correta de implementar as associações utilizando foreign keys?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode criar o relacionamento das tabelas dessa maneira:

No model de Team:

```
static associate(models) {
this.belongsTo(models.Team, { foreignKey: 'team_id', as: 'team' }); };
```

No model de Player:

```
static associate(models) {
this.belongsTo(models.Player, { foreignKey: 'player_id', as: 'player' }); };
```

Também é necessário fazer o relacionamentos nas migrations:

```
team_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    references: { model: 'Team', key: 'id' },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'SET NULL',
    allowNull: true,
  },

player_id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    references: { model: 'Player', key: 'id' },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'SET NULL',
    allowNull: true,
  },
```

Comment: valeu brother! ajudou pra caramba aqui